# How to get two columns from a left join where one tables has one joining column but the other table has 2 different columns?

Tags: sql, join

I have 2 tables with the following schema:

```
Table1  
key_sn  int
start_id    int
end_id  int

Table 2 
id  int
id_name string
```

I want to get the `id_name` corresponding to `start_id` and `end_id` in `table 1` from `table 2`.

I am using the following query to join:

```
select
       t1.key_sn
       t2.id_name as start_name
       t3.id_name as end_name

from   table1 t1 
                 left join table2 t2 on t1.start_id=t2.id
                 left join table2 t3 on t1.end_id=t3.id
```

Is there a way to get the same details without doing the `left join` twice?

Comment: Why do you never use `end_id` in your code?

Comment: You are using the same join in both, so your top select should return the same name for start and end. Are you trying to return a different name for end?

Comment: Since you are looking up two different values for two different keys I don’t see how you can do this with less than two joins.

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read...

Comment: There are other methods.  The two joins is the best approach.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can you share the other method, purely for a learning purpose.

Comment: @Yuvaraj . . . I'll give a hint:  they involve `or` in the `on` clause and than a `group by`.  That approach is really so bad that I don't want to show how to do it.